# How to make comprehensive resnet50 model structure

Tags: deep-learning, resnet

I want to make regression model using resnet50, but I got error such below:

ValueError: `input_shape` must be a tuple of three integers.

Input Shape : (1500, 89)

below is my structure

```
#Initializing ResNet50
base_model_resnet = ResNet50(include_top = False, input_shape = (89,))
#Adding layers to the ResNet50
model_resnet=Sequential()
#Add the Dense layers along with activation and batch normalization
model_resnet.add(base_model_resnet)
model_resnet.add(Flatten())
#Add the Dense layers along with activation and batch normalization
model_resnet.add(Dense(1024,activation=('relu'),input_dim=512))
model_resnet.add(Dense(512,activation=('relu'))) 
model_resnet.add(Dropout(.4))
model_resnet.add(Dense(256,activation=('relu'))) 
model_resnet.add(Dropout(.3))
model_resnet.add(Dense(128,activation=('relu')))
model_resnet.add(Dropout(.2))
model_resnet.add(Dense(10,activation=('sigmoid')))

#Summary of ResNet50 Model
model_resnet.summary()
```

Comment: ResNets take images as inputs, your input shape hints you are not passing an image.

Comment: yes,my input is not the images. so can I still use it?

Comment: From my comment you can infer that the answer is no, a pretrained resnet is trained on images, it will not work on anything else.